# USB ports stop working after a while in 18.04

Tags: usb, 18.04

My USB ports stop working a few minutes after boot and also after wake up. I am using 18.04 LTS, but this problem was also in 17.10. I have two 2.0 and one 3.0 USB ports in my [HP 15-notebook](https://support.hp.com/in-en/document/c04396296).

When I enter the `lsusb` command I get:

```
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b45e Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp.
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I also noticed that this happens when my ports are empty for a while. That means that if I plug anything immediately after boot, it doesn't happen.

I ran:

```
sudo dmesg | grep -iFe usb | tee /tmp/dmesg-usb.log
```

and I got [this output](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Vdr4pDSWV6/).

I have my Android Phone plugged in a 2.0 USB port and a SanDisk 16 GB pendrive in a 3.0 USB port, both of which I can not see in my file manager (Nautilus). And this happened after the machine woke up.

I also found that if I now suspend my laptop and wake it up immediately, I will be able to access my ports again, which I am going to do now.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you please run `sudo dmesg | grep -iFe usb | tee /tmp/dmesg-usb.log` shortly after the USB subsystem fails again, upload the resulting file `/tmp/dmesg-usb.log` to a [pastie service](//paste.ubuntu.com/) and [edit] your question to include a link to the pastie? Thanks.

Comment: Have you installed `laptop-mode-tools` (check for example with `dpkg -l laptop-mode-tools`)? If powersaving is enabled for the USB hub, that could be a problem.

Comment: Experienced this after a suspend. No usb sticks are recognized.
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/bsgkpFwS8S/
The output doesn't change after inserting/removing usb sticks.